# prove these sets are open

Tags: calculus, general-topology

A={(x,y,z): |x|<1, |y|<2, |z|<3}

B={ x: d(x,p)>r) where p, r are fixed

So for A I thought make r= min{|x|, |y|, |z|} but can't seem to manipulate the expression correctly

For B, I'm getting confused: for an arbitrary $y$ in B we need to find $\epsilon$ such that if $x$ is in the ball, $d(x,p)>r$

If someone would give me the correct radiuses as a function of the point that would help immensely.

Answer (score 1):

Here are two *hints*:

- The class of open sets is closed under finite intersections; can you write $A$ is a finite intersection of open sets?
- The complement of an open set is a closed set, and therefore the complement af a closed set is open. Can you write $B$ as the complement of a closed set?

Comment: that seems a round about way to do it, since I would then have to prove those sets are open and closed.

Comment: Not at all. The sets I am thinking of are easily seen to be open, respectively closed.

Comment: Ok so for A, it is the union of {(x,0,0): |x|<1}, ....,{(0,0,z): |z|<3} I don't know how these are easily open.

Comment: For B, the complement is an open ball correct?

Comment: Ok for A I can see it since they are all 2D balls. How about for B?

Comment: The complement of $B$ is the closure of a ball.

Comment: $A$ is expressed not as a union, but as an intersection.

Comment: So what are the sets for A?

Comment: Hint: If you have a set $A$ of elements that satisfy three conditions, then $A$ can be written as the intersection of three sets, one for each condition.

Comment: ok thanks I see. But why is the set {(x,y,z):|x|<1} open?

Comment: Hint: Can you, given a point $p \in \{ (x,y,z) \mid |x| < 1 \}$ find an $r$-ball with centre $p$ that is contained entirely within $\{ (x,y,z) \mid |x| < 1 \}$?

Comment: actually it's obvious I just need to choose r=1

Comment: Could I choose radius 1-x?

Comment: I am afraid choosing $r=1$ will not always work. Consider e.g. the point $(0.9, 7, 8)$. Choosing $\frac{1-x}{2}$ may be better. Why?

Comment: I chose r=(1-a)/2 and I get |x-a|<(1-a)/2 but when I expand I still don't get |x|<1

Comment: btw I'm only considering first element because that's all I need

Comment: Try drawing a picture.

Comment: I can see it should work but can't do the algebra to get to  |x|<1 from |x-a|<(1-a)/2

Comment: Consider a point $p = (a,b,c)$ where $|a| < 1$. Suppose $a > 0$. Let $r = \frac{1-a}{2}$. Then the open ball with centre $p$ and radius $r$ consists of points with first coordinates in the interval $(a-r,a+r)$. Clearly all these points have a first coordinate whose absolute value is less than $1$ and are therefore in the set $\{ (x,y,z) | |x| < 1 \}$. The case $a < 0$ is entirely similar.